# Need help trying to display a dynamic directory of images in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search application using SearchKit (Elasticsearch and React.) When users click on the image thumbnail of a result, a lightbox with a carousel pops up. Each result is defined by a different ID number. I have a directory of subfolders that mirror these IDs for each subfolder, with the images inside the subfolder. There are thousands of these folders.

The paths would be `"./img" + (ID) + "/" + (ID) + "-1.jpg"`,  `"./img" + (ID) + "/" + (ID) + "-2.jpg"`, `"./img" + (ID) + "/" + (ID) + "-3.jpg"`, `"./img" + (ID) + "/" + (ID) + "-4.jpg"`, etc.

I want the application to go into the appropriate subfolder, retrieve the images and display them in the carousel. The amount of images will vary between each ID number. Some have no images, others have upwards of 20.

Right now, I've just set up an array with a blanket range from 0 - 10 and tied the "-1.jpg", etc. value to the array. The obvious problem with that is that the carousel will display 11 selections, but if a file has only 4 images in it, the remaining 7 slots are broken.

This is the code I have so far:

```
const i = Array.from({length:10}, (_, x) => x)

{i.slice(0).map((i, index) => (<img 
  src={"./img/" + (ID) + "/" + (ID) + "-" + (index + 1) + ".jpg"}
/>))}
```

I can't use require.context because the path will always contain a variable. This is the closest I've come to so far, given the directory I have as it's set up.

I'm near the end of this project, and this is really the last big hurdle I'm facing. I appreciate any help in advance. New to React, so I'm trying to push it over the line.

Comment: Look into `React.lazy`, it will let you dynamically load an asset such as images. [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

Comment: @Toby I'm a little confused. Could you explain real quick? Really, what I need the code to do is go into the folder and grab all of the images, based on the ID number. I'm not seeing how React.lazy helps with that.